# Compact form for Pandas expression?

Tags: python, pandas

I recently wrote this:

```
years = pd.read_csv('assets/years.csv')
years.start = pd.to_datetime(years.start)
years.end = pd.to_datetime(years.end)
years.set_index('id', inplace=True)
years = years.drop('name', axis=1)
years = years[years.start.dt.year >= first_year]
years
```

I don't really like the way I have to re-affect my data frame each time I perform a change. Alternatively, using the `inplace=True` could be cumbersome as well.

Is there a way to compact such writing by taking advantage of the dot notation?

Here a sample example of the csv file:

```
id,start,end,name
1,2011-09-19,2012-09-16,2011-2012
2,2012-09-17,2013-09-15,2012-2013
```

Comment: can you share a sample example of the csv file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor your code nicely like this :

```py
df= pd.read_csv('assets/years.csv', index_col='id', parse_dates= ["start", "end"]).drop('name', axis=1)
years = df[df.start.dt.year >= first_year]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) docs, you can use

- `index_col` to set the index col, that replaces `years.set_index('id', inplace=True)`
- `parse_dates` to specify which columns be parsed to datetime, that replaces the `to_datetime` lines

Also
`.drop('name', axis=1)` can be chained

```
first_year = 2000
years = pd.read_csv('assets/years.csv',
                    index_col='id',
                    parse_dates=["start", "end"]) \
    .drop('name', axis=1)
years = years[years.start.dt.year >= first_year]
```